# python subprocess module changes date format

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

♠im using this command to get the timestamp ( in epoch time) of a request.

I was using the bash command date and it worked for me but using this python cmd i obtain the date in another format.

bash

```
date +%s%3N
```

bash output

```
1640426436567
```

python

```
import subprocess
start = subprocess.Popen(["date", "+%s%3N"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0]
print(str(start))
```

python output

```
b'Sat Dec 25 05:37:04 AM EST 2021\n
```

any idea how to solve this issue ?

Comment: `python output` there should be no output, are you sure it's printing anything? Anyway,  use `run` with `capture_output` and `check=1`

Comment: Why shell out in the first place and not use `time.time()`?

Comment: @KamilCuk you are rigth im printig int using print(str(start))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import subprocess
start1 = subprocess.Popen("date +%s%3N", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0]
start2 = subprocess.Popen(["date", '+%s%3N'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
print("shell=True", start1)
print("shell=False", start2)
```

Output

```
shell=True b'1640435179481\n'
shell=False b'1640435179488\n'
```

To string ->  (decode and strip)

```
start1 = subprocess.Popen("date +%s%3N", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0].decode("utf-8").strip()
```

Comment: i used the start1 example to solve the issue the only problem is that you after have to trim the result

Comment: start1 = subprocess.Popen("date +%s%3N", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).communicate()[0].decode("utf-8").strip()